# The performance overhead of instanciating multiple Mootools Classes

Tags: javascript, performance, dom, mootools

I had a thought today that maybe some of the javascript seniors can answer.

What is the estimated DOM overhead in creating multiple classes in Mootools?

Good OO design dictates that any reusable bits of code should go in a Class. But since every created Class in mootools explicitly inherits from "Class" it of course get a lot of extra instantiated.

So my  - more or less philosophical - question is, how much does that impact performance in the Browser as all code is instantiated onload and with for instance using a DTO pattern with hundreds or thousands of Classes in an array, compared to simple objects.

Ponderously,
Michael

Comment: what DOM overhead? a class is an object and if it does not create anything in the DOM then the footprint won't go there. objects are also passed by reference and inheritance won't copy from other objects (unless you `implement`, at which point it will copy object keys). what would your use case be? hundreds or thousands of classes seems like an anti-pattern. the biggest footprint will be the creation/processing time as well as all the method wrapping that takes place... please elaborate a little on your needs

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My use case I'm imagining is mapping a data set from the server into a DTO object. This list can be any length. So I'm thinking that instead of having an array of {}-style objects, then for each, make an instance of for example a PostCodeDTO and put this in the array instead. Basically wrapping the returns item in an DTO Object using for instance the Attributes mixin for Class and create a prober DTO with getters and setters etc.

Comment: sounds like you could adopt something like [shipyard](https://github.com/seanmonstar/Shipyard) or [neuro](https://github.com/GCheung55/Neuro) or even Ember or Backbone - a model -> collection structure and just define your models then let them be handled in a collection and harvest events for whatever purpose / view.

Comment: @DimitarChristoff Is this compatible with MooTools on the side? Well my question was more to the point of instantiating many instances of a MooTools Class and the overhead in memory I guess this must give, compared to simple objects holding the same data.

Comment: using mootools class is not free, there is always going to be an overhead both in (some) memory use, event stacking, cpu and all sorts. i personally use Backbone WITH mootools via an adapter https://github.com/DimitarChristoff/mootools-bootstrap that takes out jquery. the 2 linked projects are both fine - amd and based on mootools (well shipyard is mootools-like but not dependent on mootools, neuro is mootools only). Ember i can't say much about as i have not personally used it beyond a hello world model.

Comment: sorry wrong repo. https://github.com/DimitarChristoff/backbone-mootools - too many b's and m's in my list :)

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely look into these projects when I have a data heavy application. At the moment I use MooTools in a self-enforced MVC structure but data mostly bound in the DOM. I guess it's always a choice based on the use case. Backbone looks very interesting though. Seems that it would work well with the Grails ORM mindset too.

Comment: aye, that it does. add templating via say, underscore or mustache or hogan and you're laughing - define how it renders, forget about it. :)

Comment: @DimitarChristoff post an answer? :)

Comment: you should invite somebody from the mootools core team to post an answer as what i have written constitutes just my personal opinion. i can move it into an answer of sorts anyway but it's a little vague / ambiguous / abstract / subjective :)

Comment: I emailed the famous David Walsh with the question. And here is his reply: 
Good question Michael!

My opinions is that class creation is very cheap.  When you look at Dojo applications, especially the Dijit apps, those include a lot of templating, mixins, subclass, etc., and widget instantiation takes anywhere from 5-40ms, and that's for *widgets*.

Class it up! :)

David Walsh

Comment: @DimitarChristoff in case you didn't subscribe ;)

Comment: alas, i get notify for all questions i have ever posted in, and that's a lot... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right. Here is how I see this. First and foremost, a quote from @keeto:

## staying classy

''*The last part is important. While classes are a very good way to implement modular code, they’re not the only way to do it. I find that there’s a distasteful tendency nowadays for some developers to use classes for everything. Like the proverbial hammer, classes are being used for every coding nail—which is unfortunate, because not all things are supposed to be classes.*

*Classes are great for creating reusable code that can be used across projects, and I personally stick to that criteria. Unless I’m sure that something I’m building will be used more than once, I won’t turn it into a class. And in case you haven’t noticed, you can use MooTools without having to define a single custom class. After all, **just because MooTools has classes doesn’t mean you’ll have to code in JavaScript like it’s Java.****''

---

Source: http://keetology.com/blog/2010/10/01/modules-and-callbacks-going-hollywood-with-mootools

This is very subjective as it largely depends on how you write your classes and javascript in general.

Using a class is NOT without a penalty and an overhead. Dependent on the type of Class you instantiate, this will differ. For example, if your class is a simple data abstraction that does not touch other objects or output to the DOM, it is relatively cheap to make instances. The costs will be around processing options objects and (sometimes) copying properties into your instance constructor.

During Class definition itself, MooTools does loop through all constructor object properties and tries to deal with all the special ones and the mutators (eg, `initialize`, `Implements`, `Extends`, `binds` (from -more) etc). This is a one-off, though. Once the constructor function has been created, you can use it fast.

It will also do something else - it will wrap all properties that have function values so that you can decorate them as private (via `.protect()` in the current API) so any function you run will get curried for you. Additionally, you often tend to use `.bind()` as method decorators as well, which means 2 wrappers for the actual code that runs.

The more complicated your Class is (extending and implementing from different class protos), the more work can be involved in creating instances of your class. In reality, you need to create an absolute monster to start noticing this as anything other than memory allocation (delays on start or garbage collection). Of course, cpu-heavy or async / blocking stuff in constructor functions won't be nice either, if you do it lots...

Events, event listeners and so forth can also stack up. 
Saved references to objects will stack up over time.

Then, there are classes that bind to DOM elements, add events, listen to events, export their own events...

Put it all together and it can become somewhat costly. You are creating Objects that inherit (hopefully by reference via the prototype chain) from many places. Even so, the definition of your class constructors itself is fast and it won't be until you create 1000s of instances that things will start getting interesting and put a modern browser to the test.